# On idempotents and local property of $\Lambda \otimes_R R_{\mathfrak p}$ where $\Lambda$ is module finite algebra over commutative local ring $R$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, maximal-and-prime-ideals, local-rings

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian local ring. Let $\Lambda$ be a module finite associative $R$-algebra.  Let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal of $R$. I have the following two questions:

(1) If $\Lambda$ has no non-trivial idempotent elements, then does $\Lambda \otimes_R R_{\mathfrak p}$ have no non-trivial idempotent element?

(2) If $\Lambda$ has a unique maximal left ideal, then does $\Lambda \otimes_R R_{\mathfrak p}$ have a unique maximal left ideal ?

Comment: What have you tried? And what is the context?

Comment: [Crossposted to MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/460023/19965).  I don't know for sure the sentiment for timing on crosspostings on MO, but I can say here crossposting after just one day is not recommended.  Usually it's recommended to wait multiple days.  If there's no attention at all, one could delete the original and repost in the new location without crossposting. Even if there is some reason to crosspost, one should always link the two questions.